# Kubernetes cluster certificates rotation

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm looking for some advice on the procedure of certificates rotation. I have been practicing to install a cluster from scratch with Kelsey Hightower's [Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md). It has been great to understand the certificates needed to build trust between components that form a Kubernetes cluster.

But consulting the official documentation about certificates rotation I 've only found [this resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/), which mentions only the kubelet component.

I guess that the idea of certificate rotation would be to change all af the certificates involved: controller-manager, kube-proxy, scheduler, api-server, etc.

So, my questions are:

- Are there any resources about the subject that you would recommend?
- Is there an order I should follow in the update of the components to minimize the service disruption? I imagine there will be a period where there will be communication problems because some components will be using the old certificates and some others will be using the new ones
- Say I backup the old certificates (create a copy in a different path) and replace the current files with newly generated certificates. Will I still need to restart the system units (or static pods / regular pods) that include some certificates configuration or will the configuraton  be "hot" reloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would be better managed by a [side-car proxy service such as Istio](https://istio.io/blog/2019/data-plane-setup/)

It offers certificat ttl out of the box, [with by default 90 days](https://istio.io/faq/security/#cert-lifetime-config).
The [rotation is not automated though](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13832#issuecomment-517984230).
Using an [external provider like Let'sEncrypt can help](https://medium.com/@gregoire.waymel/istio-cert-manager-lets-encrypt-demystified-c1cbed011d67) (as [described here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/best-practices-for-a-tls-server/75517)).